# Unfriendly "backtick" char for Italians

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I am an Italian most-of-time-Windows-developer and I would like to request some sort of improvement in question/answer/comment formatting when facing the backtick char `` ` ``.
As I said I am Italian and on my Italian layouted keyboard I have no backtick key. More, I'm a Windows developer, so I have no the `Alt Gr + '` shortcut to add it (like Linux, for example, does). I am also a Firefox web-user and the `Ctrl + K` shortcut focuses the search box for typing a query for search engine.

The way I have to follow in order to use it is `Alt + 96`, by ASCII code, that are 3 keystrokes with an hold. Well, the problem is not specific to the amount of keystrokes, most of my problem for example is to remember the backtick ascii code to type it (actually I had to Google for it to type it here), because in Italy is not much of a use since it is not included in common language.

Of course I don't even try to say to substitute it (it would be overwhelming for those used to type it), but I would suggest to provide an alternative char for those, like me, that face this uncomfort.

In order to try to make the question constructive I'll suggest few possible combinations: what about, say, `£` char or `°` char or a combination of more apostrophe chars like `'''some code'''`?

Comment: Or a button in the toolbar above the editor, so select text > click button > text gets enclosed in backticks.

Comment: Three apostrophes or the like makes a fair amount of sense, but then isn't that just as much typing as Alt+96?

Comment: That button exists already, @JonasCz.

Comment: *More, I'm a Windows developer, so I have no the Alt Gr + ' shortcut to add it (like Linux, for example, does).* What do you mean? I have a French keyboard and the backtick combination is `AltGr + è` on both Linux and Windows. Also, I run Firefox and `Ctrl+K` does work as intended, provided you have given focus to the edit box beforehand (which is usually the case, since you're editing).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I mean that I'm not aware of a keyboard combination for producing the backtick on an Italian keyboard but through ascii code. If I push Ctrl+K the cursor jumps to the Google box on Firefox GUI to query.

Comment: I've heard of combination AltGr+' producing backtick just on Linux, not in Windows, even in Italian layout (didn't test that in Linux though, did in Windows and doesn't work).

Comment: @JoshCaswell still not for comments though.

Comment: @TechNyquist, interesting. [This SuperUser question](http://superuser.com/q/667622/94017) reveals that you may be able to produce backticks by hitting `AltGr + +` if your Windows uses Italian layout 142. Otherwise, `AltGr + '` should work.

Comment: Stack Overflow uses Markdown, a language over which they have no control, so changing it to a different character is probably a non-starter. The answers have workarounds which may or may not help mitigate the problem.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi switching to Italian 142 layout actually introduces the backtick and even tilde char. But it also moved `@ # € { [ ] }` chars to totally different buttons... given this and what @Mike said, I fear I'll have to keep ALT-coding that backtick. Anyway thank you for the layout tip, I totally missed it.

Comment: Fair enough, @TechNyquist, didn't think of that.

Comment: I had the same issue.
I solved creating an [italian-developer keyboard](http://superuser.com/a/598465).

Comment: @Francesco `Ctrl + F` shows search-in-page box, while `Ctrl + K` shows search-in-web "Google" box. The Firefox version is the very same.

Comment: When I used Windows I really liked [AllChars](https://sourceforge.net/projects/allchars/) to insert special characters. It's like the Compose key on X11 systems. I don't know if it still works with Windows 8/10 though, but it worked well with Windows 7.

Answer (score 5):

There are many keyboard macro programs available (e.g. like [FingerTips](http://www.getfingertips.com/), which I use) that let you easily substitute strings as-you-type. You could e.g. have it automatically change `-bt-` or `!bt!` to two backticks. That's still 4 characters to type instead of 2, but they are in your normal typing flow.

Just use a short string that you are unlikely to use as 'real' text. Fingertips (and probably others) has the added advantage that it demands you to type those characters in one sequence: `-ba`<kbd>backspace</kbd>`t-` will **not** do the substitution in my example (so if for any reason you are editing stuff and temporarily have a `-bt-` sequence in your text it will not get substituted).

Answer (score 2):

There is two ways to format the code and text instead of **backtick**.

1. You can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> after selecting the text that you want to format.
2. You can use the tool that is appear in each section of Question and answer, above side, Here is screenshot:

[image]

You can use mouse to format the text by clicking on the tool.

Comment: Agree, but Ctrl+K combination, as explained, is calling Google search box in Firefox, not formatting text. While the format toolbar is available in question and answer edit, not for comments, where backtick is required.

Comment: @TechNyquist  try ctrl+k after selecting the text in Firefox, will not call Google Search. I have test it.

Comment: @CodeLover I tested it already and test it again now to be sure: even selecting the text my cursor jumps to the search box leaving the comment unedited. Naughty cursor :)

Comment: @TechNyquist its working on my browser. can you please check the version of browser or try after update it.

Comment: @CodeLover my Firefox is 37.0.1 and claims to be up-to-date.

Comment: @TechNyquist it won't work in comments, only in posts.

Comment: @jonrsharpe indeed. Thus my question :)

Answer (score -2):

I made a layout based on Italian plus Linux shortcuts to get tilde and backtick: code and installer are [here](https://github.com/ilpianista/itlinux-win-keyboard).